# Model dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, modeling

The query which is always done: Based on UID and upload_year --> get document
I would think UID is my PK and upload_year as SK?

How should I model my dynamodb?

```
UID (pk) name   email             document                upload_year (sk)
1        Parker m.parker@mail.com random_doc.txt          2019        
1        Parker m.parker@mail.com random_second_doc.txt   2020
2        Peters p.peters@mail.com random_doc.txt          2019
```

OR

```
UID (pk) name   email             document                upload_year (sk)
1        Parker m.parker@mail.com 
2        Peters p.peters@mail.com
1                                 random_doc.txt            2019
1                                 random_second_doc.txt     2020
2                                 random_doc.txt            2019
```

or even another option?

Comment: is there a possibility for an item with same UID to be uploaded multiple times a year?

Comment: Your table's primary key is a composite of partition key (uid) and sort key (year). This primary key must be unique per item so you are limiting your design to one upload per user per year. It seems odd that you would have an 'upload year', but maybe that's reasonable, I don't know what you're modeling. Another option would be to have an 'upload date/time' and, independently, a non-key attribute that was the 'upload year', thus allowing multiple uploads per user per year.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks. I can update the upload_year to an actual unique timestamp. (There will not be an upload at the same time for a same user). Still it's not very clear how to organize my rows. I will have the name/mail/uid already in my dynamodb and latter I will add the documents. Will I update the rows with new attributes (first solution above) or would I add new rows (second solution)?

Comment: I would think I need PK UID and sort key (timestamp) but I will only have a timestamp when there are docs, not when a user is just added.

Comment: I think you’re saying that a user item will exist before any document is uploaded. Ordinarily you would have a User table, that is independent of the Documents table.